# counting rows where column value match, over all distinct column values - sql

Tags: sql, database

I'm using SQL and this is my goal:

Starting table:

```
anime_uid, reviewer, score

1, james, 8
1, john,  7
2, sam,   5
1, alice, 7
3, john,  5
2, alice, 4
```

My goal is to know how many times an anime was reviewed, and what is the avg score. meaning i need to have something like this:

```
anime_uid, times_reviewed, avg_score
1, 3, 7.33
2, 2, 4.5
3, 1, 5
```

I can't seem to deconstruct the query to sub-queries to complete this task, would love your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT
    anime_uid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT reviewer) as times_reviewed,
    AVG(score) as avg_score
FROM table
GROUP BY anime_uid
```

Comment: it worked! thanks! can you try and help me how to deconstruct the query into small ones? what was your way of thinking here?

Comment: i dont get your question very well, like getting `times_reviewed` and `avg_score` with two sub-query ?

Comment: I think i'm using the terms wrong, i mean sub query like a mini task, e.g. counting the times reviewed for each distinct ```anime_uid```.
and a follow up question, how can i use ```times_reviewed``` in a parent query? for example, i want to filter rows where their ```times_reviewed``` is below X

Comment: you can use `HAVING`:

`SELECT
    anime_uid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT reviewer) as times_reviewed,
    AVG(score) as avg_score
FROM table
GROUP BY anime_uid
HAVING times_reviewed < X
`

Comment: that worked. I think i need to go over the commands again. thank you for your help!